# What is "workmanlike manner"?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I have to ask this because I have been doing a ton of electrical work in my house.  Will get inspected soon.

I am pretty neat - everything is stapled uniformly and ran at the same height- but I don't always make my cables face the same way.  They have some twists.  My framing holes are off by an inch here and there.

So my question is - what is workmanlike manner?  What is the cut-off?  If you have pictures of something that didn't pass because of this please show it - especially if you think it was workmanlike.

Answer (score 7):

Workmanlike manner is a really subjective term. It is a catch all for neat, orderly and following the rules. A lot of inspectors fail an inspection using that term when actually specific violations are numerous.  Common items such as not securing wires close enough to plastic boxes, crossbeaming, sagging cable, holes drilled too close to the edge of joists, lack of nail protection plates, bla bla bla.  Typically a lot of the look nice, finish up work can fall into this category. If your work looks neat, tight, and orderly, you should be fine. If the inspector finds some minor problems, thank him or her for pointing them out and if small enouth, fix them while they are still there. Debating with an inspector is futile and will invite a much more intense evaluation that could result in a lot more findings.  Ask them for advise and treat it like a learning experience.  Good Luck.

Comment: What is crossbeaming?

Comment: Wasn't looking to debate the inspector.  If anything they are a little easy on electric in my area because I have seen some messes pass.  I just keep seeing the term used and I have seen jobs fail because of it.  It just seems that if they have a subjective term in code that there should be a couple of reference points.

Comment: @DMoore; wasn't suggesting you might debate with an inspector, just saying, because it happens all the time and a DIYer will not win the debate.  @Argento; cross beaming is running wires under joists or beams and stapling them up, rather than boring holes at the right spot and chasing wires thru them.